# SWIG how to access a byte array from a c struct in Lua using a Lua table to manipulate

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, lua

I am trying to access a array in a c struct from Lua. I want to access it as byte array. I know I have to use
typemaps somehow but I am not able to get it working like I want to.

the struct is defined within a namespace if that matter at all. For this example
I call the headerfile send.h

```
namespace foo{
namespace bar{

typedef struct 
{
    ...
    unsigned char data[8];
} message;

}};
```

So I want to be able to access the unsigned char data array from the c struct from Lua. 
I want to access it like a table with numbers. Here my Lua script code I want to
use.

```
modul = require("MyModule")
msg = modul.message()

msg.data[1] = 0x3b

print(msg.data[1])
```

All what I get is an error like "attempt to index field 'data' (a userdata value)"
I did some research and found out that I have to add some kind of %typemap magic to
deal with that. But I was not able to figure out exactly how.

So here my questions:

- Can someone point me to a working example of that scenario?
- What kind of typemap should I apply?
- How can I apply such a typemap only to this struct and not to others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I figured out that simple by using below typemap I'm able to access the data member just the way I want to. Hope that will help someone else.

```
%typemap(out) unsigned char foo::bar::message::data[8]
{
    int i;
    int32_t _size = 8;

    lua_newtable(L);
    for (i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number)$1[i]);
        lua_rawseti(L, -2, i + 1);
    }

    SWIG_arg++;
}

%include "send.h"
%{
#include "send.h"
%}
```

Comment: Hi! Im having pretty much the same problem as yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724937/lua-swig-set-get-float-array) however using your solution it is not working for me. You sure you can set and then print the right value using this solution?

Comment: @McBob I did not check stackoverflow for a while - hopefully you could solve the issue yourself.