# swig lua set get element array

Tags: c, lua, swig

How to generate a typemap to handle the set and get of a float array. I got the following structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    float p[2];

} Point;
```

What I should write in my swig interface file to be able to write the following in Lua code:

```
MyPoint.p[1]=123.456
print(MyPoint.p[1])
```

I tried the solution from there:

[SWIG how to access a byte array from a c struct in Lua using a Lua table to manipulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233920/swig-how-to-access-a-byte-array-from-a-c-struct-in-lua-using-a-lua-table-to-mani)

But it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Could you expand upon "it doesn't work for me", please??

Comment: The affectation MyPoint.p[1]=123.456 does not generate no error, but the print always return 0.